# Efficient collision detection between balls (ellipses)

Tags: html5-canvas, collision-detection, processing

I'm running a simple sketch in an HTML5 canvas using Processing.js that creates "ball" objects which are just ellipses that have position, speed, and acceleration vectors as well as a diameter. In the draw function, I call on a function called applyPhysics() which loops over each ball in a hashmap and checks them against each other to see if their positions make them crash. If they do, their speed vectors are reversed.

Long story short, the number of calculations as it is now is (number of balls)^2 which ends up being a lot when I get to into the hundreds of balls. Using this sort of check slows down the sketch too much so I'm looking for ways to do smart collisions some other way.

Any suggestions? Using PGraphics somehow maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're already simplifying the physics by treating the ellipses as if they were circles.

Other than that, check out quadtree collision detection:

http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space/

I don't know your project, but if the balls have non-random forces applied to them (e.g. gravity) you might use predictive analytics also.

Comment: Yes to the circles and I love that quadtree algorithm! Thanks! I'll start trying to implement it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you grid the space and create a data structure that reflects this (e.g. an array of row objects each containing an array of column objects each containing an ArrayList of ball objects), you can just consider interactions within each cell (or also with neighbouring cells).  You can reassign data location for balls that cross boundaries. You then have far fewer interactions.